# How to make deployable software which uses libraries that do not have apt-get options with CMake

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I wrote a piece of software which works well on my own box. It has been a headache to get it onto another box, though.

The main problem is that there is a library which it uses which is not a library covered by apt-get; it's called pngwriter. And pngwriter is also very finicky, and it is not very easily installed. It also has version compatibility issues. To get around all of that, I thought it would be great to include the source for pngwriter with my project, and have CMake go ahead and make pngwriter with the rest of the code.

So my main question is: Is this type of deployment canon? Should CMake call the makefiles that the developers of the software already wrote, and then use `FIND_PACKAGE` locally, or will I need to rewrite all of their makefiles so that I can use `ADD_LIBRARY`?

Comment: Can you create a pngmaker .deb package?

Comment: I don't know; I've never tried making a .deb package. I'll look into that as another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [`ExternalProject_Add`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module%3aExternalProject) function.

The docs are OK, but there is a [decent article](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html) which explains things in a bit more detail.  From this article:

> The `ExternalProject_Add` function makes it possible to say “download this project from the internet, run its configure step, build it and install it”

Bear in mind that you can skip the install step altogether, or you could choose to install to a location inside your own build directory.